# nginx fastcgi return allowed memory size exhausted instead of not found exception

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, exception

I have a website, written in Symfony2.
when users want to access a route which doesn't exists, PHP returns

> FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   PHP message:PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes)
>   symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FlattenException.
>   php on line 296

which is in `flattenArgs` function: (i think it gets in loop but i don'y know why)

```
elseif (is_array($value)) {
  if ($level > 10) {
    $result[$key] = array('array', '*DEEP NESTED ARRAY*');
  } else {
    $result[$key] = array('array', $this->flattenArgs($value, $level + 1, $count));
  }
}
```

I have increased the `memory_limit` value in my php.ini, and also checked my configs. The other sites with same config written in pure PHP are working safe and write.

But naturally it should return 404, not found exception.

Comment: hi, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @poh yes yes :)
you shouldn't use security context (isgranted) in error twigs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the solution!
you shouldn't use **security context** in error twigs. in my case i was using `is_granted` in header, processing some kind of errors is before defining security context.

you can pass it by first checking user object and then security context.

for example `{%if app.user and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')%}`